# HTML insertion using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="container" class "container-class">
   <ul class="table-list">
     <li id="element1" class="listless">
        <div class="table-list-cell">
           <span class="labels">...</span>
               INSERT HTML HERE
           <div class="div">
```

I want to insert a label at the spot marked in the code

How do I do this in Javascript?

I had an attempt that didn't work here

```
function addLabel($label) {
  $('#container .table-list').append($label);
}
```

Comment: The selector you mention doesn't refer to that point, so that's not going to work, even if the statement in itself would work. You could try to insert something *after* `#element1 .labels`.

Comment: Create an id for insert content 
`<div id="something">INSERT HTML HERE</div>`
and in script
`$('#something').html('your html goes here');`

Comment: i can only inject HTML, the original source isn't mine. its apart of a chrome extension im working on

Answer (score 2):

Try using Jquery [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/), and change selector to locate last object before the position where you need to add the text (eg : `.labels`)

```
$('#container .table-list .labels').after('New Label Value');
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6dexgjow/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery append() function to achieve this.

```
$('#container .table-list .labels').append('New Label Value');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cbLko845/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Just get the `.div` which is after your inserted data, and insert content before this `.div` by using jquery [.before](http://api.jquery.com/before/).

```
function addLabel($label) {
  $('#element1 .div').before($label);
}
```

by inserting content before the div, will insure that your inserted content always remain in order, in which you are inserting.

you can use jquery [.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/) with `.labels`, but it will reverse content order, in which you are inserting.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you're appending a label `$label`. Your example hints that before the line `INSERT HTML HERE` you have a span containing labels `<span class="labels">...</span>`. 
So perhaps just you need to *append* it to the list of existing labels in your html.

Your selector changes slightly to include `.labels`

```
$('#container .table-list .labels').append($label);
```

Alternatives to this include using [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/), [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) but others have already offered answers for these.

Personally I think you should introduce a container so you can explicitly append in the right place.

```
<span class="labels">...</span>
<div id="append-container"></div> <!--INSERT HTML HERE-->
<div class="div">–

$('#append-container').append($label);
```

Most UI frameworks that allow for view composition work by getting the developer to define regions/containers for were the sub-views/components should be added.

In any event unlike using solutions with `.after()` and `.before()` this will not break later on if you change the html such that the selectors for your *after* and *before* solution no long match. You have to update you selector to mirror the changes (assuming you remember to check the javascript - the next developer that comes along might not).

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery** :

```
function addLabel($label) {
    $('.table-list .labels').append($label);
}
```

Alternatively, you can always go with pure javascript if you want some speed into that:

**Javascript**:

```
function addLabel(label) {
    var list = document.querySelectorAll('.table-list .labels');
    [].forEach.call(list, function(element) {
        element.appendChild(label);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's [**.after()**](http://api.jquery.com/after/) is what you're looking for.

And if what you want is inserting a `<label/>` element, you can use `$('<label/>')` *([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2))* to create it.

This is a full example:

```
function addLabel(content) {
    var label = $('<label/>').text(content);
    $('#container .table-list-cell .labels').after(label);
}

addLabel('label text');
```

Check it out on **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcr26dtu/1/)**.

*Note: by the way, you forgot the equal sign on your #container class attribute.*